# How can integration tests be written for these kinds of components?

Tags: testing, vuejs3, integration, vue-test-utils, vitest

It is my first time writing an integration test for these kinds of components. Please help me or provide an example or any tutorial on that.

My component is in Vue 3, and I am using the vitest framework and Vue Test Utils for testing. Here is my component code:

```
<template>
  <suspense>
    <PopularArticlesContainer />
    <template #fallback>
      <PopularArticlesLoading />
    </template>
  </suspense>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import PopularArticlesContainer from"@/components/GuestHome/popularArticles/PopularArticlesContainer.vue";
import PopularArticlesLoading from"@/components/GuestHome/popularArticles/PopularArticlesLoading.vue";
</script>
```

Really, I can't determine which steps I can follow to test components like that.